# Redirect subdomain to subdomain+folder

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, subdomain

I've linked a subdomain to my Tomcat app, but I don´t want to put the name of the folder to access. I've done this using Apache as a proxy.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.example.com.pe
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass /SSHR http://192.168.10.52:8081/SSHR
  ProxyPassReverse /SSHR http://192.168.10.52:8081/SSHR
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried with this lines:

```
ProxyPass / http://192.168.10.52:8081/SSHR/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.10.52:8081/SSHR/
```

It works, but I've some problems with the Tomcat application. So, what I need is something to redirect from example.domain.com.pe to example.domain.com.pe/SSHR.